# How to save user data across app updates?

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am building an app for the Samsung Galaxy Watch (Tizen OS via html/css/javascript).

The user is able to set individual settings in the app / enter custom information.

**Question:** How can I ensure that this user supplied information is saved between app updates?

**Wanted Outcome:**

1. User installs app version 1.
2. User inputs data into app version 1.
3. An update to app version 2 becomes available.
4. User updates to app version 2.
5. User data supplied in app version 1 is available in app version 2 (after update).

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please paste your code here and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Ahmad, I do not have any code. I am rather asking for a general guidance. I was thinking about generating a unique user id (tied to the watch) and upload the user input from the watch app to a server. When an app update happens, it would connect to the server first, to check whether any user input existed, and download it from the server. Thus, a complete wipeout of the app during the update process could be circumvented. But I do not think this is a good approach, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can preserve application's setting using `tizen.preference.setValue(key, value)` and retrieve it by using `tizen.preference.getValue(key)`

I think this page will be helpful : 
https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/application-management/application-preferences?langredirect=1

Comment: I think it is worth noting if planning to use this Preference API know that's values can only be of a primitive type; string, number, or boolean..